# How do I create technical design architectures' illustrations?

Tags: software-recommendation, illustration

I came across a few technical architecture designs on websites like these:

[image: architecture design image]

(Above image doesn't have a background so please open it in a new tab as an image)
[image]
[image]

Can you guys give me any idea on which software/website can I build such technical architecture designs on?

Comment: THis question is hard to quantify. Thing is if you know how to draw than its pretty easy to teach you to do this in any number of applications but if you DONT know how to draw on pen and paper then your dead in the water,

Comment: Practically *any* drawing or painting software *could* create these. It all boils down  to desired end use and proficiency with any particular tool (software). Nothing is going to drawn similar things for you - which is why artists still have jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line drawing in the beginning of the question can be drawn in any 2D drawing program. As vectors you can make it in Inkscape, Illustrator, Serif Affinity series programs and numerous others. As bitmap image you can draw it in Photoshop, GIMP, Serif Affinity series programs, Krita, Paint.NET and numerous others. Some of the mentioned programs allow both output types.

Not asked, but if for some reason I should draw something which resembles your line drawing example I would use pen and paper. By having a background grid and a ruler it would not need especially polished skills assuming the drawing idea is clear.

The colored versions need some care. They seem to use isometric projection of apparently 3D objects. The mentioned 2D graphics programs above are still valid for them, too, but the isometric projection support varies. For ex. Affinity Designer has special isometric drawing mode which allow the actual drawing to happen as straight on the face shapes and texts. They can be turned to the isometric view automatically. In other programs one should use isometric grid and skew texts and other items which are easiest to draw as straight, but are needed on surfaces. The isometric drawing mode is handy, but it's not at all a must. I guess one can save only 10% of the work with it.

The transparent glass and glow -like effects in your 3rd example need substantial amount of experience before one can draw them confidently. I would try to cheat and draw at least most complex transparent objects in a 3D program to get the "seen through" parts right with low effort.

Not asked: With 3D programs one is not limited to easy projections like to the said isometric view. Other projections can be made with zero effort by rotating the view. In 2D programs every view must be drawn as a separate image.

The existence of your question suggests that you must start your drawing attempts from zero experience. If that's true prepare to practice patiently several weeks before you get done something worth showing and months before you can create something as complex as your 3rd example. A paid artist makes it fast for you, if needed.

If these shapes are not only images, but contain also a logical structure with technical properties and relations and that structure should be included to the drawing, no drawing-only program is OK and everything said above is useless. In that case the question should contain that requirement to avoid more useless answers.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! It helped a lot!! I am actually a developer and not a designer and wanted to understand the process behind designing such drawings so I could hire accordingly. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think you'd even need something with some specific isometric drawing mode.  A simple isometric grid could be used in virtually any vector image editor - Illustrator, Inkscape, Corel Draw, etc.

Comment: @KrushnalPatel Maybe start with a tutorial for some free software such as Inkscape.  There's a good one here: https://youtu.be/toWMFcWB4HA - enough to get the basics of creating isometric designs, or at least help you get the gist of what is involved and whether it's something you think you'd be able to do.